# jquery validation not working in ie9 , ie8 , ie7 ,ie6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

hi i am using jquery validation plugin and jquery in my application . the validation works in `Firefox` , but not working in any `IE` version . i don't know why . please help

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->config->item('3rd'); ?>jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->config->item('3rd'); ?>jquery/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>

var jq = jQuery.noConflict(); 

jq(document).ready(function(){      

    var x=jq("#test").validate({                        

        rules: {
            fname: {
                required:true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 250   
            },              
            lname: {
                required:true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 250                  
            }
        },

        messages: {
            fname: {
                required: "Enter your Business Name",
                minlength: "At least 3 characters long",
                maxlength:"Maximum length allowed is 250 charactors"
            },                         
            lname: {
                required: "Enter City",
                minlength: "min length 3",
                maxlength:"Max length 250"
            }
        }

    }); 


});

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" id="test">
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br /> 
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no errors given , form just submit , it ignores the validation

Comment: u haven't put `class="required"` on both input field. try with that. and also set `id` for both input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mm i found the problem . i think `jquery-1.6.2.min.js` is not working with jquery validation in `ie` . i changed it to `jquery-1.3.2.min.js` and it worked , thanks ....

Answer (score 1):

I just worked through a similar issue myself where the validation was working in every browser except IE9.  In my case IE9 had an issue with a comma.

I used the developer tools (f12) then clicked the Console tab.  If there's an error IE will tell you the file and line number it's having trouble with.

This solved it for me.

Normally I wouldn't use an older version of Jquery (or anything else for that matter) to solve an issue because of the potential security risks you may expose.  However you may find that the version you went with is still secure.